# insert id param in url for form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form that shows multiple existing records - i.e. a different record on each row - using the fields_for function.

There is a submit button on each row, so that if the record on that row is modified, pressing the submit button on that row will save the updated record.

When the submit button is pressed, I want to call the 'update' method and pass through the id of the record as a url param (e.g. units/update/1) and the edited record values as form params (i.e. params[])

My issue is that I can't get the id of the record to be passed through as a param in the URL. i.e it calls 'units/update', instead of 'units/update/1'

The relevant code in my view is:

```
<%= form_tag url_for( controller: "units", action: "update"), method: "patch", :html => {:id => "edit_form"} do %> 

    <% for unit in @units %>
      <%= fields_for "units[]", unit do |f| %>

        ** code to display/capture form information goes here **

         <td> <%= submit_tag "update" %> </td>

    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The relevant code in my routes.rb file is:

```
resources :units, except: :show
```

The error that's generated is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"units"}
```

How do I pass the id in as a param in the URL?

Comment: I think you would be better off using form_for unit in place of fields_for and have a separate form for each unit, since that is the behavior you have described... using fields_for doesn't really make sense here...